# unchecked exception while running regex- get file name without extention from file path

Tags: c++, regex

I have this simple program

```
string str = "D:\Praxisphase 1 project\test\Brainstorming.docx";
regex ex("[^\\]+(?=\.docx$)");
if (regex_match(str, ex)){
    cout << "match found"<< endl;
}
```

expecting the result to be true, my regex is working since I have tried it online, but when trying to run in C++ , the app throws unchecked exception.

Comment: You should escape backslashes `\\\`.

Comment: Double escape the dot and use `regex_search`.

Comment: Please post the exact text of this exception. Note also that your string needs to double-up the backslashes.

Comment: how could i double escape the dots_ could you please post an answer

Comment: Glad my answer worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use raw string literals when defining regex to avoid issues with backslashes (the `\.` is not a valid escape sequence, you need `"\\."` or `R"(\.)"`). Second, `regex_match` requires a *full string match*, thus, use `regex_search`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str = R"(D:\Praxisphase 1 project\test\Brainstorming.docx)";
    // OR
    // string str = R"D:\\Praxisphase 1 project\\test\\Brainstorming.docx";
    regex ex(R"([^\\]+(?=\.docx$))");
    if (regex_search(str, ex)){
        cout << "match found"<< endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/TUduSD)

Note that `R"([^\\]+(?=\.docx$))"` = `"[^\\\\]+(?=\\.docx$)"`, the `\` in the first are *literal* backslashes (and you need two backslashes in a regex pattern to match a `\` symbol), and in the second, the 4 backslashes are necessary to declare 2 literal backslashes that will match a single `\` in the input text.

Comment: I guess he also want `"D:\\Praxisphase 1 project\\test\\Brainstorming.docx"`

Comment: :) Sorry, did not pay attention. Fixed now.